# Finding the minimum MSSQL compatibility level

Tags: sql-server

I know I can use something like this

```
select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name = 'database'
```

to find out the database compatibility level, but what I'm actually looking for is the minimum that this server supports. Is there a dynamic way of doing this? Or do I have to hard-code the values?

**Backgroud:** We have a large number of customers using a wide variety of servers and proving our system against all servers is problematic. If I can set it to a low compatibility level, that I know is well-proven, that's better than setting to high/default. (i.e. it's better - in our scenario - to set a new database on SQL Server 2012 to compatibility 90, than to 100 or 110).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do is get the server version (with `SELECT @@VERSION`) and then compare that with a list that maps the server version to the supported compatibility level: http://sqlrus.com/2014/10/compatibility-level-vs-database-version/

I note that the list on that link is incorrect insofar as a SQL Server 2014 server I run supports Level 90, but the page says it should only support Level 100.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the unfortunate solution. Thanks for confirming. The official documentation also says that 2014 doesn't support 90...maybe you're running a CTP?